# How to hide wp admin menu form all

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, admin

I want to hide all wp admin menus except 2 or 3 menus from everyone, even from me(administrator).

how can i do this

NOTE: i don't want add_role or something else, just hide menus form everyone

Comment: You can use this light plugin. wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this bro, hope it is helpfull for you

```
// Remove menu functions.php
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
    $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Media'), __('Links'),  __('Appearance'), __

('Tools'), __('Users'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'));
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin.

You can Add, Edit, Re-Order and hide admin menus from this plugin.

Follow this link http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-edit-re-order-or-hide-wordpress-admin-menus/ for external help.

### Update:

Add this code into your `functions.php` file and do the changes according to your need.

```
function remove_menus(){

      remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
      remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
      remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
      remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
      remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
      remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
      remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
      remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
      remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Take a look on [remove_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page)

Comment: sorry jogesh i notify in my question that no admin roles and i also do don't want use any plugin only use code

Comment: @Nadeem __"only use code"__ have you tried anything yet?

Comment: no bcoz i have no idea how i do this, bcoz team leader says do not use plugin

Comment: @Nadeem take a look on updated answer hope this will help you.

Comment: @Nadeem I think, i deserve for a +1 and yes don't forget to close this question to mark it accept. ;)

Comment: Sorry bro i have only 4 repu and for voting i must be at 15 repu, so Sorry..............i don't know y i get -1 on my question and please tell me how can i close my question

Comment: @Nadeem you have closed, you get -1 i think because you have to do some research, and have to share your code as well. This is in community rules. Anyway happy to help you :)

Comment: we can use this light plugin. wordpress.org/plugins/hide-admin-menu